# How to get Excel to Add small fractions

Tags: excel, vba, fractions

So this might be more of a mathematical question then coding but hopefully you can help anyway. Basically I want Excel to count a list of fractions that get incrementally larger so for example 1/265 + 1/264 + 1/263 + ..... 1/n where n would be the final number in the Do While Loop.

However every time I run this macro I just get 0 fed back to me. I have messed around with all the figures and have realized that if I start my fraction at 1/50 then it will work, but anything smaller then that even 1/51 and no matter what it will generate 0 just.  It seems that when a fraction gets to small VBA just recognizes it as zero and refuses to work with it. Is this something anyone else is familiar with or is it a limitation of the system?

If anyone wants to test it i have listed a few numbers below that can be used as a replacement for r and what the final output should be (FYI the formula is definitely correct).

r    ;  Answer (rounded):

46   ;   50

99   ;   124

156  ;   235

```
Sub DoWhile()

Dim i As Integer
i = 6

Do While Cells(i, 5).Value <> ""

Dim r As Variant
r = Cells(i, 5).Value

Dim a As Integer
a = 265

Dim z As Integer
z = 0

Dim x As Integer
x = a


    Do While (x >= (a - r + 1))

        z = z + (1 / x)
        x = x - 1

    Loop

Cells(i, 6).Value = (z) * (a)
i = i + 1

Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: `Integer` are *Integer*, that means they contain no remainder. `z = z + (1 / x)` will always stay zero because `1 / x` is zero when you don't have a remainder. Change to datatype `Double`

Comment: @FunThomas If I could use the face palm emoji I would!  I like to think I am decent at maths and I learnt what an integer was when I was probably 12! Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need VBA for this.

```
E6: Your "counter", eg `46`
```

Excel O365:

```
=SUM(1/SEQUENCE(E6,,265,-1))*265
```

Earlier versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/ROW(INDEX($A:$A,265):INDEX($A:$A,265-E6+1)))*265
```

Answer (score 0):

As @FunThomas mentions in a comment:

> `Integer` are *Integer*, that means they contain no remainder. `z = z + (1 / x)` will always stay zero because `1 / x` is zero when you don't have a remainder. Change to datatype `Double`

I needed to change `Integer` to `Double` and that worked perfectly.